# Grubbs test: two/one-sided'nes and degrees of freedom

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, outliers

There are two things which confuse me about the **Grubbs-test**:

(1) The first aspect involves the two or one-sidednes of the test:
Lets assume I want to check if my W6 dice, where I expect the probabilities to be $p_i=1/6$ each, is biased. I throw the dice $n$ times and get $h_i$ as frequencies for my $m=6$ categories $i\in \{1,\ldots,6\}$. My statistic is

$$\begin{align}
\chi^2=\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{(h_i - n p_i)^2}{n p_i}
\end{align}
$$

Now here it makes sense to say one performs a one-sided test with this quantity since the closer this value is to 0 the higher the probability that my dice is not biased.
In case of the **Grubbs-test** I have the absolute value of the difference of the possible outlier $X^*$ and the mean value $\bar{X}$
$$
R^* = \frac{\left|X^* - \bar{X}\right|}{s}\quad\text{with}\quad \text{max}_i|X_i - \bar{X}|=|X^* - \bar{X}|\;.
$$
Thus, comparing it to the **Chi-squared-test** above I can argue in the same way to justify why a one-sided test makes sense. However, in the case where the absolute value is take the test is a two sided one, see e.g. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grubbs%27s_test)

(2) The other point concerns the degrees of freedom which is $(n-2)$ in case of the **Grubbs-test**. I understand the reduction by 1 due to the fact that we use the expectation value, as in the **t-test**. But where does the other reduction come from?